# Data processing by php

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php and I have been sin saber Where you go and see if you can give me an idea.
The case is as follows:
I'm reading a website and writing on it:

```
<?php

$ archivo ="prueba.html";
$ abrir= fopen($archivo,"r");
$ contenido = fread($abrir, filesize($archivo));
fclose($abrir);

if (isset($ _ POST['input2'])) {
    $ Output = $ _ POST['input2'];
    $ archivo = fopen("prueba.html", "w");

    fputs($archivo);

    $ archivo ="prueba.html";
    $ abrir = fopen($archivo, "r");
    $ contenido = file_get_contents($archivo);
    fclose($abrir);
}

?>
```

Now I have the variable content of all data of the website.

How do I access the content of the variable CONTENT Modify a paragraph or title of the website

Comment: Don't put space between `$` and the variable name.

Comment: `fputs()` needs two arguments -- what are you writing to the file?

Comment: @Barmar: It can't work: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foo' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'` for `$ foo = 'bar'; echo $ foo;`

Comment: Oh, I just assumed it works because he didn't say he was getting an error.

Comment: Pardon me the translator fault .
What I need is to try to change the content of a div or paragraph or change an image
and I have every data page in the Variable CONTENT
It does not know how to treat that variable

Comment: did you try using regex?

Comment: I need to know how to access these data and to modify them through a text area and I have to be modified to give the send button

Comment: I've warped it all together in the answer bellow. hope that'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use regex to do that:

Find content and show it example:

```
preg_match("/(<tag>)(.*)(<\/tag>)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Inner content will be: `$output_array[2]`

Replace content in tag example:

```
$newContent = "new_tag_content";
preg_replace("/(<tag>)(.*)(<\/tag>)/", "$1" . $newContent . "$3", $input_lines);
```

This is a good site to check your regex in php: [online_php_regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Now, grab it all together:

Form page to edit new content:

```
<?php
    $input_line = getMyFileContents();
    preg_match("/(<tag>)(.*)(<\/tag>)/", $input_line, $output_array);
    $oldContent = $output_array[2];
?>

<form action="action_page.php" id="usrform">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="newContent" form="usrform">
    <?php echo $oldContent; ?>
</textarea>
```

The "action_page.php" where the data would be changed:

```
<?php
    /* get new content from the posted form */
    $newContent = $_REQUEST["newContent"];
    $newContent = "new_tag_content";
    $input_lines = getMyFileContents();
    /* change the content */
    preg_replace("/(<tag>)(.*)(<\/tag>)/", "$1" . $newContent . "$3", $input_lines);
    /* write $input_lines to your file */
    functionToChangeYourFileContents($input_lines);
```

P.S.
you can use also use ajax for this